# Accepting response of res.write() from browser

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I'm trying to implement a payment gateway from my back-end and I'm using 'payhere' checkout-api which is an external payment api. After sending a post request to the API it's supposed to redirect the user to the checkout page of payhere. But since I'm doing this through my own back-end api of my project I'm using the following method

```
res.set(data.headers);
res.write(data.body);
res.end();
```

the code worked fine when I called my own api through postman but when I tried it with a html file I created locally on my machine it does't display anything. The code of my html file is as follow

```
fetch('https://digicense-api.herokuapp.com/users/fines/pay', {
                method: 'POST',
                redirect: 'follow',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'text/html',
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer _token_',
                }
            }).then(function (res) {
                console.log(res)
                return JSON.parse(res)
            }).then(function (data) {
                console.log(data.json())
            })
```

How do I fix this so that the browser will display the page that is redirected by the external api? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try changing your backend to do a redirect: res.redirect(301, $url_of_the_redirected_page);

Comment: Please do not post tokens / keys in cleartext

Comment: @EamonnMcEvoy I already tried redirecting using the url but then it gave a error of missing required parameters